# Unable to retrieve the captured Image inside the onCreate method

Tags: java, android, web-services

So, far this is all I have done to retrieve the images in a variable and encode them into a base 64 string so, that it can be sent to a webservice. But every time I receive null values in the base 64 String. And secondly I cannot access the bitmap image outside OnActivityResult. Here is my code.

```
{

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST=1888;
private ImageView imageVw;
public String encodedImage="";
public String path;
private static final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL="http://10.0.2.2:2278/newWebService/WebService.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/insertData";
private static final String METHOD_NAME="insertData";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);}

    this.imageVw=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
    Button photoButton=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick2);

    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
            EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etComplnt);



            PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            pi.name="name";

            PropertyInfo pi2=new PropertyInfo();
            pi2.type=pi2.STRING_CLASS;
            pi2.name="complnt";

            PropertyInfo pi3=new PropertyInfo();
            pi3.type=pi3.STRING_CLASS;
            pi3.name="img";

            request.addProperty(pi,ed1.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty(pi2,ed2.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty(pi3,loadImageFromStorage(path));

            SoapSerializationEnvelope env=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            env.dotNet=true;
            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE htse=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try{
                htse.debug=true;
                htse.call(SOAP_ACTION, env);
                Object response=env.getResponse();
                TextView txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg3);
                txt2.setText(response.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), encodedImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView txt7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg7);
                txt7.setText(encodedImage);
            }

            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                TextView txt6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg6);
                txt6.setText(exc.toString());
                System.out.println("Dump : "+htse.responseDump);
            }

        }
    });


   // String strBase64=Base64.encodeToString(returnPic(req, res, data), flags);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    returnPic(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void returnPic(int req,int res,Intent data)
{
    byte[] bits = null;
    if(req==CAMERA_REQUEST && res==RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imageVw.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        String  imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        /**ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BitmapDrawable drawable=((BitmapDrawable)imageVw.getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap=drawable.getBitmap();**/

        path= saveToInternalStorage(bitmap);

        //ByteArrayOutputStream bytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bytes);
         //byte[] imageBytes = bytes.toByteArray();
        //encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
       // FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(getPath(selectedImageUri));
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

public String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage)
{
    ContextWrapper cw=new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory=cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File myPath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos=null;

    try{
        fos=new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    }

    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}

private String loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{
    String encoder = null;
    try{
        File f=new File(path,"profile.jpg");
        Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bytes);
        byte[] imageBytes = bytes.toByteArray();
        encoder = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encoder; 
}
   }
```

Any help appreciated because I have been stuck on this thing from about a week. What I want to do is simply capture the image and send it to a C# webservice using SOAP.

Note: Through this code it is sending 0X (null value) in the database.

Comment: This is not c#, its java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys Here it is. This is how I solved my own problem. I just simply saved the captured image at a location in SD card and then used the same location to retreive the same captured image and then use it anywhere in my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST=1111;
private ImageView imageVw;
public String encodedImage;
private static final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL="http://10.0.2.2:3694/WebService.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/insertData";
private static final String METHOD_NAME="insertData";

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);}

    this.imageVw=(ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
    Button photoButton=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick2);

    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
            EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etComplnt);

            Bitmap bmp=retreivePic();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

            PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            pi.name="name";

            PropertyInfo pi2=new PropertyInfo();
            pi2.type=pi2.STRING_CLASS;
            pi2.name="complnt";

            PropertyInfo pi3=new PropertyInfo();
            pi3.type=pi3.STRING_CLASS;
            pi3.name="img";

            request.addProperty(pi,ed1.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty(pi2,ed2.getText().toString());
            request.addProperty(pi3,encoded);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope env=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            env.dotNet=true;
            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE htse=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try{
                htse.debug=true;
                htse.call(SOAP_ACTION, env);
                Object response=env.getResponse();
                TextView txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg3);
                txt2.setText("Sent");
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), encoded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //TextView txt7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg7);
                //txt7.setText(encoded);
            }

            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                TextView txt6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg6);
                txt6.setText(exc.toString());
                System.out.println("Dump : "+htse.responseDump);
            }

        }
    });


   // String strBase64=Base64.encodeToString(returnPic(req, res, data), flags);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bitmap thumb=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    //img.setImageBitmap(thumb);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"image.jpg");
    try{
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    }

    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Bitmap retreivePic()
{
    File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"image.jpg");
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
    return bmp;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get your image from camera in onActivityResult

```
byte[] b = bund.getByteArray("data");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
String base64Str = encodeTobase64(bmp); //base64Str is the one that you want to send to the webservice.



public string encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
    String imageEncoded;
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    if ( immagex != null )
    {   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    else
    {
        imageEncoded = "";
    }
    return imageEncoded ;
 }
```

=== Edit :

If you want to get the bitmap from the imageview onclicklistener

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: How can I access this base64Str outside onActivityResult i.e. in onCreate method or on any button seton click listener. That was my question @Nayra Ahmed.

Comment: To have the encoded image out side you can use your global variable `encodedImage` instead of `base64Str` so you can use the encodedImage in onCreate method or on any button seton click listener

Comment: I did it but then it was giving me the same 1 st image captured everytime.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question more . If you need to send multiple images to the webservice. You can create an arrayList and add the encoded images to it every time you capture a new image then send encoded images one by one to the webservices. or you can send every images after capturing it immediately in `onActivityResult' . The way you use to send them will depends on your project requirements and how is the webservice working .